# Lighthouse & Polymer: start_url in manifest is not cached by Service Worker

Tags: caching, polymer, polymer-starter-kit, polymer-2.x, lighthouse

I'm testing my Polymer application and I get a pretty good score on Lighthouse. However, I still have a small problem. I have a `manifest.json` file containing everything so the app can be added to the home screen, but Lighthouse still gives a failure saying: `Manifest start_url is not cached by a Service Worker.`. I'm using the Polymer Starter Kit 2.0 and I have no idea how to cache it with the Service Worker. I have a `sw-precache-config.js` containing:

```
module.exports = {
  staticFileGlobs: [
    '/index.html',
    '/index.html?launcher=true',
    '/manifest.json',
    '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*',
  ],
  navigateFallback: '/index.html',
};
```

Where `/index.html?launcher=true` is the start_url of the manifest.

Comment: Are you using `http/2` push? I am getting the same error from Lighthouse after I (only) implemented pushing resources.

Comment: No, I'm not using http push

Answer (score 0):

I think in your "index.html" file you have :

```
rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"
```

You have to change it by :

```
rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"
```

You can find a codelabs provided by Google's team here :
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/add-to-home-screen/#3